# Secure Communication Protocol Against Dictionary and Replay Attacks

Tags: encryption, dictionary, rsa

I am trying to implement a basic secure channel between two parties that can defend itself against dictionary and block replay attacks.

I want to use the RSA public key cryptosystem as a means of securing the channel. However, I would like to know if the following scenario is effective:

1. A generates a private and public key
2. A send B the public key
3. B encrypts the message with the public key
4. B sends the encrypted message to A
5. Now A can decrypt the message using the private key.

Now this is all well and good. However, what if A would like to send a message securely to B. Does this mean we need two pairs of keys. So A would have B's public key and B would have A's public key? Is this true? Does this feasible? Also, some form of random hashing or padding will be needed to prevent block replay attacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Diffie-Hellman key agreement](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2248), a protocol to allow two parties to establish a (shared) private key while only communicating publicly. Protection from replay attacks can come from renegotiating the keys frequently so that replayed messages can't be decrypted by the receiving party, and/or by including a timestamp in the encrypted message and a limited window of acceptability at the receiving end.